# Unable to separate elements of JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, chart.js

I am trying to create data for use in a chart.js plot using C# Controller and javascript. My Controller method returns a JSONResult to a javascript function.

```
public JsonResult GetPlansPerDoc(){
     //Code to grab data from database
     foreach (RadOnc ro in radOncs){
          pm = new CKPlanTypeDistributionPlotModel()
                {
                    DPName = ro.LastName,
                    DPValue = ro.Plans.Count()
                };

                planList.Add(pm);
            }

            JsonResult data = Json(planList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            return data;
 }
```

Here's the Javascript code calling the Controller method.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: "@Url.Action("GetPlansPerDoc", "HomeData")",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (rawData) {
                console.log(rawData);
                const data = rawData.DPName;
                console.log(data);
```

When I console.log the rawData I get an Array message in the web console with the four items in the json result. However, when I try and use one of the fields of the json result I get an "unknown" error in web console. How do I use the json data?
​

Comment: Have you tried JSON.parse(rawData) ?

Comment: Simon yes. I get the following error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data. I believe that is because rawData is already in a json format.

Comment: Can you show us the JSON?

Comment: is rawData an array?

Comment: What do you see on the console?

Comment: When I console.log(rawData) I get Array(4) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]   For console.log(data) I get Undefined.

Comment: @PaulSinnema Which JSON do you want to see? What's coming out of the Controller method?

Comment: JSON should be a string I guess. Don't quite know the JsonResult you use but my guess is it should result in a string on the client.

Comment: With JSON I always use NewtonSoft JSON.Net

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938907/json-net-and-actionresult

Comment: I performed a console.log(typeof rawData) and it said json. Let me do it again though. And I'll look at your so link

Comment: console.log(typeof rawData) yields object.

Answer (score 1):

Playing around I used the following process. I remembered rawData[0] would give me the first item. SO I tried rawData[0].DPName and it successfully gave me the first name. So I guess I'll just use the following code to extract the elements.

```
rawData.forEach(dp =>{
     xLabels.push(dp.DPName);
     yData.push(dp.DPValue);
}
```

Would love to know if there's a more direct way though.